# Convert macro to a function but cannot concatenate inputs using std::stringstream

Tags: c++, macros

I currently have a macro:

```
#define MY_MACRO(cond, msg)                    \
    do                                         \
        {                                      \
            if (!(cond))                       \
            {                                  \
                std::cout << msg << std::endl; \
                std::abort();                  \
            }                                  \
    } while(0)
```

it's used to check boolean conditions and output a message if they fail.

Here's basic usage:

```
int p = 7;
MY_MACRO(false, "test (" << p << ")");
```

I'd like to replace it with a function like this:

```
static inline void MY_MACRO(const bool cond, const std::stringstream& ss)
{
    if(cond == false)
    {
        std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
        std::abort();
    }
}
```

However, `std::stringstream` doesn't seem to replicate the previous behavior because I'm getting compiler errors where the second parameter is passed in:

```
<source>:39:30: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const char[7]' and 'int')
   39 |     MY_MACRO(false, "test (" << p << ")");
      |                     ~~~~~~~~ ^  ~
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: @TheNomad I don't think so? It's probably even simpler than that. I want to convert my macro to a function but I don't want to have to change any of the current calls to the existing macro. Because the macro just expands it doesn't need a C++ type to handle `"test (" << p << ")"` whereas now I have a function I need a type to handle that concatenation.

Comment: How did you call the `MY_MACRO` function? Why do you want to convert that macro to a function? They are 2 different concepts with different purposes, not synonyms. My point is, it's like saying "i want to use `decltype` at runtime, because it works when I compile so why doesn't it work when I call it in my function with a param?"

Comment: @TheNomad Deleted my message. Will post again...

Comment: As I said, they serve different purposes. So instead of breaking what works, why not focus on fixing or avoiding the errors? Not nitpicking here, it is just a more pragmatic approach: instead of changing whatever X mechanism so it can work with one addition, but break 47 old ones, make a new macro or just call the function for the new one. Isn't that with less impact? It will avoid regression errors as well. I know it's not the answer you're looking for, but seems to me like you're asking for complications and a few nights of intensive unneeded debugging if other "legacy" things break.

Comment: @TheNomad I want the macro to call a function within a namespace which will send a message via something like Whatsapp/Signal/Telegram. This new function has signature of a string. When I added this, I got compiler errors. This made me want to replace the macro with a function, but now I think about it, it was probably the same errors, trying to convert `"test (" << p << ")"` to a string. So I still have the same problem, I think?

Comment: So you called the function the same way: `MY_MACRO_FUNC(false, "test (" << p << ")");` ?

Comment: @TheNomad yes, otherwise I have an awful lot of code to change. I think my question is simply how to concatenate different types, using the `<<` operator, for use with a stringstream (or string) argument type.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't add the pseudo `InstantMessage::WhatsApp::SendMessage(msg)` in the macro itself after the `cout` call instead of replacing the macro itself with a function? By then it's expanded and stringified.

Comment: @TheNomad That's what I did, but what type should I use for the argument to `SendMessage()`? I think it's the same problem?

Comment: Well, isn't the `msg` treated as a pseudo-string (well, as much as chars can be text)? So have you tried `std::(w)string` (depending on your preference)?

Comment: @TheNomad I've tried std::string, std::stringstream and std::ostream. None of them seem to allow `MY_MACRO(false, "1" << 2 << "3")`.

Comment: Try a #stringify macro call on the param in the pseudo messaging call inside the MY_MACRO code before or after cout-ing: `InstantMessage::WhatsApp::SendMessage(TO_STRING(msg))` with a std::string signature. Theoretically, it should work, but you might get some extra quotes, which I guess you could cleanup in `SendMessage()` since by then it'd theoretically be a string. I am clutching at straws without seeing much of what you actually want to do, since it's more than just a random POC question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so a short POC based on our short chat would be this:

```
#include <iostream>

#define STRINGIFY(text) #text
#define TO_STRING(text) STRINGIFY(text)

#define MY_MACRO(cond, msg)                    \
    do                                         \
        {                                      \
            if (!(cond))                       \
            {                                  \
                std::cout << msg << std::endl; \
                WhatsAppMsg(TO_STRING(msg));  \
            }                                  \
    } while(0)

    static void WhatsAppMsg(const std::string str)
    {
        // add your WA or Telegram API call here after string sanitization by removing unwanted characters
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int p = 7;
        MY_MACRO(false, "test (" << p << ")");

        return 0;
    }
```

The output is this:

> ASM generation compiler returned: 0
> Execution build compiler returned: 0
> Program returned: 0
> test (7)
> "test (" << p << ")"

Just remember to cleanup the stringified quotes, which should be easier now since it's a standard string.

Of course, while this has least regression impact, if you'll do an external webservice call, then all kinds of crazy things can happen (such as network, certificate or server errors) so an exception can still be triggered; even if it doesn't, you should still be able to handle it as a regular error.

Also consider to not track any error from inside the messaging function with your macro to not end up in a vicious loop.

Anyway, this should get you started and in the right direction with what we discussed.